# Building a XMLRPC client using xmlrpc-epi in PHP?

Tags: php, xml-rpc

I have xmlrpc-epi installed on my Apache server and I need to use it to connect to a XMLRPC server. What I should do - is there anything I need to download and/or install on my server in addition to the xmlprc-api?

```
xmlrpc
core library version    xmlrpc-epi v. 0.51
php extension version   0.51
author  Dan Libby
homepage    http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net
open sourced by     Epinions.com
```

I wasn't able to find relevant code examples which clearly highlights how to form a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one example with xmlrpc-epi:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xmlrpc.php#40176

Comment: I have not used xmlrpc-epi before, i mostly played with WordPress xmlrpc. You can also check this page from zend devzone to get some ideas on building xmlrpc clients: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1307

Comment: do i need to do - include("utils/utils.php"); // from xmlrpc-epi utils   ? isn't everything included already in a standard php setup?